# Why i am getting Terminated due to timeout in this code on Hackerrank? My last iteration is not taking place?

Tags: java, algorithm, timeout

Question-Little Bobby loves chocolate. He frequently goes to his favorite  store, Penny Auntie, to buy them. They are having a promotion at Penny Auntie. If Bobby saves enough wrappers, he can turn them in for a free chocolate.

For example, Bobby has  to spend on bars of chocolate that cost  each. He can turn in  wrappers to receive another bar. Initially, he buys  bars and has  wrappers after eating them. He turns in  of them, leaving him with , for more bars. After eating those two, he has  wrappers, turns in  leaving him with  wrapper and his new bar. Once he eats that one, he has  wrappers and turns them in for another bar. After eating that one, he only has  wrapper, and his feast ends. Overall, he has eaten  bars.

Function Description

Complete the chocolateFeast function in the editor below. It must return the number of chocolates Bobby can eat after taking full advantage of the promotion.

chocolateFeast has the following parameter(s):

n: an integer representing Bobby's initial amount of money
c: an integer representing the cost of a chocolate bar
m: an integer representing the number of wrappers he can turn in for a free bar
Note: Little Bobby will always turn in his wrappers if he has enough to get a free chocolate.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer, , denoting the number of test cases to analyze. 
Each of the next  lines contains three space-separated integers: , , and . They represent money to spend, cost of a chocolate, and the number of wrappers he can turn in for a free chocolate.

Constraints

Output Format

For each trip to Penny Auntie, print the total number of chocolates Bobby eats on a new line.

Sample Input

3
10 2 5
12 4 4
6 2 2
Sample Output

6
3
5

I have tried this using the following code-

```
static int chocolateFeast(int n, int c, int m) {
    int bars=n/c;
    int wrapper=bars;
    int sum=bars;
    while((wrapper/m)!=0){
        bars=wrapper/m;
        sum+=bars;
        wrapper=bars+bars%m;
    }
return sum;
}
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t,n,c,m,total;
    t=sc.nextInt();
    for (int i=1;i<=t;i++){
        n=sc.nextInt();
        c=sc.nextInt();
        m=sc.nextInt();
        total=chocolateFeast(n,c,m);
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

}

Input (stdin)
3
10 2 5
12 4 4
6 2 2
Your Output (stdout)
6
3
Expected Output
6
3
5

Comment: Pretty sure your loop never ends in the third case

Comment: no actually it gives only 2 output . the last loop doesnt execute.

Comment: You get stuck in the `while` loop in the 3rd case is what he means, which is true

Comment: so i should change the conditions in while loop?

Comment: You should write down the logic you are doing and do the final case by hand and make sure it makes sense, your problem isn't the "code" itself, it is the logic you have used.  The final while loop never goes below or equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2:

I read the question wrong, and have changed the code according to M Oehm.  The code below seems to work now.  You were checking for `bars%m` instead of `wrapper%m`

```
    static int chocolateFeast(int n, int c, int m) {
        int bars=n/c;
        int wrapper=bars;
        int sum=bars;
        while((wrapper/m) != 0){
            bars=wrapper/m;
            wrapper=bars + wrapper%m;
            sum+=bars;
        }
    return sum;
    }
```

I checked the output for the sample you provided and it outputted `6 3 5` correctly.

Comment: Where in the question does it say that you can trade in wrappers only `m` times? As I read it, `m` is just how many wrappers you need to get another chocolate bar. In my opinion, the error is that the OP calculates how many bars you can get, but doesn't remove the wrappers: `wrapper = wrapper % m + bars`, where `wrapper % m` are the wrappers after trading the rest in.

Comment: @M Oehm Yeah looks like you are right, I read "m: an integer representing the number of wrappers he can turn in for a free bar" as number of times, and then this outputted the expected output so I didn't think I read it wrong.

Comment: thank you for your help Nevexis ..i tried to figure out the my logic and this is what i did- 
        while(m<=wrapper){
            previous=bars;
            bars=wrapper/m;
            sum+=bars;
            wrapper=bars+(previous-m*bars);
        }
   it works perfectly